# How can I convert the contents of a list to upper without using .upper()?

Tags: python, list

I'm not allowed to use .upper in my code but i'm lost as to why this doesnt work.
some of my inputs are "AgtGtGcC" "AAtcccgG"

```
import sys
seqs = []
for i in range(len(sys.argv)):
    seq = sys.argv
    seqs.append(seq)
def uppercase(seq):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    result = ''
    for x in seq:
        for pos in range(52):
            if alphabet[pos] == x:
                i = pos
        if x not in alphabet or i>=26:
            result += x
        else:
            result += alphabet[i+26]
    return result
uppercase(seq)
    
print(seqs)
```

Comment: Can you try using a dictionary? Map all the lower cased to upper cases and then use that to convert?

Comment: You don't need a loop to find the position, you can use the `index()` method.

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? Can you be more specific? I'd guess it's because you call the function but don't use its return value. Perhaps you meant to do `print(uppercase(seq))`?

Comment: It will raise an error when you will check a non alphabetic char.

Comment: Instead of a string with both uppercase and lowercase alphabets, why don't you use two strings? Search for the character in the lowercase string. If it's found, use the same index in the uppercase.

Comment: Not a solution for your code but an alternative implementation that just needs an import of the `string` module: `return seq.translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase))`. That's the full body of the function.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `seqs.append(seq)`? That creates a nested list containing all the command-line arguments.

Comment: I think your code about `uppercase()`  just fine... at least on the input S.

Comment: @Matthias that is almost certainly against the spirit of the assignment...

Comment: your function works perfectly... the problem is the `sys` part. `sys.argv` is a list and you pass the list the function which is nonsense. I think that the question/code has heavy indentation problem!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That will teach the teachers to give better assignments. But we could switch to `return ''.join(chr(ord(c) - 32) if 97 < ord(c) < 122 else c for c in seq)`. Should be OK - at least for ASCII letters. (edit: I just see, that S3DEV has presented kind of a long version of this as an answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think your function does work (unless you will encounter non alphabetic char).

However your script dosen't do what you think. look at this lines in the end:

```
uppercase(seq)
    
print(seqs)
```

You are only running your function on one example, and you print the test strings and not the results. Maybe you should change it to something like this:

```
for seq in seqs:
    print(uppercase(seq))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lower-level (C-esque) approach using the ASCII table and the `map` and `ord` functions.

The function operates by testing the passed character is in fact, lower case (so you don't end up with symbols in the converted value). If the character is lower case, it's converted to upper case; otherwise the original character is returned.

Finally, the string is mapped (via the `map` function) against the `upper` function, where the string is joined together for the final result.

Example code:

```
def upper(c):
    """Convert lower case to upper case."""
    if 97 <= ord(c) <= 122:
        return chr(ord(c)-32)
    else:
        return c

string = 'AgtGtGcC'
result = ''.join(map(upper, string))
```

Output:

```
'AGTGTGCC'
```

---

Documentation references:

- [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map),
  [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord),
  string [join](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: Nice `low level` on ASCII code map.

Comment: I think there is a bug on the `ord(c) >= 122`. The symbol needs to be `<=` otherwise it is true for anything above 97. (e.g. `chr(ord("}")-32)` becomes `']'`). Also, maybe `if 97 <= ord(c) <= 122` for readability?

Answer (score 0):

The logic of this is simple: if the character is lowercase, convert to the corresponding uppercase, otherwise, include it as is.

```
def uppercase(seq):
    lowers = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    uppers = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    result = ''
    for x in seq:
        if x in lowers:
            result += uppers[lowers.index(x)]
        else:
            result += x
    return result

seqs = 'Hello, How Are You?'
uppercase(seqs)
 # HELLO, HOW ARE YOU?
```

Comment: Perhaps consider using `string.ascii_lowercase` and `string.ascii_uppercase` rather than defining the alphabet manually.

Comment: Good advice, but I have a feeling that the OP has some unusual restrictions on imports or certain functions.

Comment: Fair play.  Restrictions == homework!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with ASCII characters to convert lower case character to upper case character.
Only point to note over here is you should know how ASCII characters work.

Answer (score 0):

The function works good but you mess up with command line interface, here the doc for [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html). Here how to fix it:

File: `upper.py`

```
def uppercase(seq):
    # original implementation of the OP, no change applied
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    result = ''
    for x in seq:
        for pos in range(52):
            if alphabet[pos] == x:
                i = pos
        if x not in alphabet or i>=26:
            result += x
        else:
            result += alphabet[i+26]
    return result


# here the right function call with the CLI-parameters
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    for seq in sys.argv[1:]: # the 0 entry is always the file name, so skip it!
        print(uppercase(seq))
```

From the command line:

```
$ python3 upper.py 1212 check check: hallo tHere!
```

Output

```
1212
CHECK
CHECK:
HALLO
THERE!
```